# Arcs from a Delaunay Triagulation

Tags: spatialite, network, delaunay

I am trying to generate a Cost Distance table using Spatialite.
I have several points in the table random_points for which I would like to compute the Delaunay triangulation and use the segments it produces as arcs. 
Something like:

```
SELECT ST_DelaunayTriangulation(ST_Collect(Geometry)) FROM random_points;
```

And the reuse its output. How can this be achieved?

Alternatively, I have thought about generating the lines connecting each pair of random points (there will be millions of these, the total number of random_points is around 4000) and then to keep those that appear in the Delaunay triangulation. Something of that sort:

```
WITH dela AS (SELECT ST_DelaunayTriangulation(ST_Collect(Geometry), 1, 0) FROM random_points), 
  g1 AS (SELECT mergename, geometry FROM random_points), 
  g2 AS (SELECT mergename, geometry FROM random_points) 
  SELECT g1.mergename, g2.mergename, AsText(MakeLine(g1.geometry, g2.geometry))  FROM g1, g2 WHERE MakeLine(g1.geometry, g2.geometry) IN dela;
```

Any idea how to tweak it if the syntax is right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the core of your problem is that you want to extract the individual line from the collections `ST_DelaunayTriangulation`. That can be done by `ST_GeometryN` and a little SQL trick to create a table containing a range of numbers.

```sql
CREATE TABLE delaunay_segments AS
WITH
    dela(lines) AS (
        SELECT DelaunayTriangulation(Collect(Geometry), TRUE)
        FROM random_points
    ),
    vals(n) AS (
        SELECT 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT n+1 FROM vals
        LIMIT (SELECT NumGeometries(lines) FROM dela)
    )
SELECT GeometryN(dela.lines, vals.n) AS Geometry
FROM vals, dela;

SELECT RecoverGeometryColumn('delaunay_segments', 'Geometry', 4326, 'LINESTRING');
```